# How is Aggregate Supply(Willing) equal to National Income(Actual)?

Tags: macroeconomics, producer-theory, aggregate-production, national-income, input-output

Acc. to definition of Aggregate Supply

- It is the total value of final goods and services that the *producers* are ***willing*** to supply in country .

Definition of National Income

- It is the value of *total* *output* ***produced*** by normal residents of a country in given period of time .

AS is what producers are *wanting/willing* to supply i.e it is *not the actual output produced*

Whereas National Income is the value of output produced i.e it is the *actual value of output that has been produced.*

Then how can we say that Aggregate Supply *(Willing)* = National Income *(Actual)* ?